# Python - Brute Force - Memory Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou trabalhando nesse código que gera sequencias com todas as possibilidades dos caracteres introduzidos(your_list)

```
your_list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
complete_list = []
for current in range(10):
    a = [i for i in your_list]
    for y in range(current):
         a = [x+i for i in your_list for x in a]
    complete_list = complete_list+a
print (complete_list)
```

Estou encontrando o erro destacado abaixo, mas não sei como resolver este problema

```
"C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\markestrat\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/markestrat/venv/brutef.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/markestrat/venv/brutef.py", line 65, in <module>
    a = [x+i for i in your_list for x in a]
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/markestrat/venv/brutef.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    a = [x+i for i in your_list for x in a]
MemoryError
```

Alguém sabe como resolver este problema?

Comment: Qual seria o resultado pretendido? Todas as combinações entre as letras do alfabeto? Com quais tamanhos? Com substituição ou não? A ordem importa? Isto é, `ab` e `ba` seriam equivalentes ou não?

Comment: [ab] e [ba] não seriam equivalentes, por enquanto estou apenas testando, então o tamanho não faz muita diferença agora, uns 4 ou 5 caracteres já está bom, mas o problema é quando faço algo com muito mais caracteres, ele acusa Memory Error, como neste exemplo de 10 caracteres, mas com 4 ou 5, o programa funciona normal e de forma rápida, a partir do sexto caractere ele acusa erro

Comment: Sim, porque você guarda todas as combinações em uma lista. Isso não é necessário e já adianto para você estudar geradores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode obter as letras minúsculas do alfabeto com:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
```

Se quiser todas as letras, incluindo maiúsculas, `string.ascii_letters`, ou somente maiúsculas, `string.ascii_uppercase`, ou qualquer valor disponível em [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html).

Para gerar todas as combinações possíveis de `N` caracteres, sem repetição, mantendo a ordem dos mesmos, você pode utilizar [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
from string import ascii_lowercase

print(list(combinations(ascii_lowercase, 2)))
```

O retorno disso seria

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ..., ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'z'), ('y', 'z')]
```

Assim, você poderia definir uma função que gera todas as combinações possíveis sem repetição fazendo:

```
def all_combinations(iterable):
    size = len(iterable)
    for i in range(1, size+1):
        yield from combinations(iterable, i)
```

Isso gerará todas as combinações possíveis de 1 a 26 caracteres, sem repetição e mantendo a ordem, mas sem armazenar todos os valores em memória. Como é utilizado geradores, cada valor é gerado sob demanda, implementando o que chamamos de *lazy-evaluation* e, assim, contornando o problema de memória apresentado na pergunta.

**Notas**

1. O retorno é um objeto iterável de tuplas com a combinação; se é desejável uma *string*, deverá ser tratada essa conversão;
2. Todas as combinações respeitam a ordem dos caracteres de entrada, assim é gerada a combinação `('a', 'b')` mas não a `('b', 'a')`;
3. Todas as combinações são sem repetição, não gerando sequências com o mesmo caractere como por exemplo `('a', 'a', 'a')`; se for desejado com repetição, utilize [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement);

Comment: Mas como eu faço pra não dar MEMORY ERROR? Quando o tamanho de caracteres cresce ele buga, no seu código quando coloco combinações de 6 caracteres da o mesmo erro que o meu (MEMORY ERROR), eu queria poder solucionar esse problema pra depois acrescentar letras maiúsculas, numero e caracteres especiais, e sim, eu precisaria de que ele levasse em conta repetições e também  apresentasse combinações como ('a', 'b') e ('b', 'a')

Comment: @LuisFernandoGarcia A única coisa que foquei na resposta foi justamente em resolver o problema de memória ao utilizar geradores ao invés de lista. Se continuou dando o erro, provavelmente você tentou armazenar tudo em uma lista novamente. Quanto ao caso de considerar repetições ou a ordem eu não inclui na resposta porque julguei ser fora do contexto da sua pergunta e coloquei comentários para que você pudesse implementar por conta.

Comment: Eu apenas aumentei o tamanho do seu "n", não alterei nada  -- print(list(combinations(ascii_lowercase, 2))) -- coloquei no lugar desse 2 um 6

Comment: @LuisFernandoGarcia A solução é a função que eu criei, essa linha foi apenas para exemplificar o uso/retorno da função.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito Obrigado